# Crazy widths using SimpleModal in IE9

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, simplemodal, internet-explorer-9

Has anyone else tried using SimpleModal in IE9? If so, have you experienced that the width of the modal is wildly wrong?

I checked on the homepage for SimpleModal, and the modals are all over the place width-wise there as well.

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: Finally got the Developer Tools working in IE9 (seems using hardware rendering crashes IE9 on a Mac running Win7), and discovered the issue. It seems the width being set inline on the container are being incorrectly calculated. Forcing IE8 standards mode is a temporary salve (things work fine again), but then we lose out on all the other niftyness of IE9. Ideas, folks?

Comment: I'll look into it at time allows, but considering IE9 is still in beta, it doesn't surprise me that there are issues.

Comment: No worries Eric, and yeah, no surprise there's JS issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just released SimpleModal 1.4.1 - see if that resolves your issues.

http://code.google.com/p/simplemodal/downloads/list

Comment: Thanks Eric, I'll check it out & let you know!

Comment: So, I finally circled back around to this on another project, and I can confirm things are a-ok with the widths in IE9 now, so thanks! However, there is something else that's come up, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507078/ie9-isnt-apply-font-face-fonts-for-a-modal-after-its-shown

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I have managed to come up with is to surround the SimpleModal divs that you are creating with another div that specifies the width.

Essentially it seems that the divs will always go to 100% of the container they are in, so use other divs to contain their size, and keep them in alignment.

Comment: Well, the SimpleModal script should be calculating the correct width of the container based on the size of the div you're turning into a modal, but it seems to go haywire in IE9 document mode & be unable to figure out the correct width. I'm curious how you managed to create yet another div around the simplemodal-container div on-the-fly.

Comment: Yeah the widths are calculated properly in every other browser except for IE9, and I'm pretty sure the issue is IE9 being still in beta, however I discovered issues with the containers not staying in place when I collapsed some containers. To solve that I started wrapping my 2 seperate columns in divs and then noticed it fixed the width issue in IE9. However if you want to do it on the fly you could use the jQuery http://api.jquery.com/wrap/ to wrap the SimpleModal in a div.