# IE9 isn't applying @font-face fonts for a modal after it's shown

Tags: internet-explorer-9, font-face, simplemodal

So, I've got a page w/ a SimpleModal on it, and fonts are applied via Typekit (which uses some tricky JS to set up some `@font-face` rules) and everything is just dandy.

Except for the modal itself; when you click to open it, the `@font-face` fonts aren't applied, so things look janky. If, however, you close it & re-open it, or you use the Developer Tools, the font is suddenly magically applied.

Anybody seen this?

Comment: Do you have sample code or a page I can see?

Comment: Oh, lord, that was bone-headed. Yep, here you go: [www.gattsound.com/wp/news/](http://www.gattsound.com/wp/news/). Click the "client login" link to open the modal. BTW, that URL may change tomorrow, to [www.gattsound.com/news/](http://www.gattsound.com/news/); I'm launching that site. Thanks as always!

Comment: Talk about bone-head...I don't even have IE9 installed :P Anyway, can you try passing clone:true to the modal? $(element).modal({clone:true}). See if that works...

Comment: It works! Also, a heads-up, don't install IE9 if you want to keep IE8. I need to have two separate Windows installs for IE testing (one w/ IE7 & IE8, another w/ IE9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Eric provided the answer (considering he's the developer of SimpleModal, that makes sense.)

Anyway, just need to add `clone: true` to the call for the modal, like so:

```
$(element).modal({clone:true})
```

And then IE9 renders `@font-face` stuff right away! Brilliant.